# Better way to output PHP objects to console?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to find the best way to debug PHP in the browser.

EDIT:

I know about xdebug, var_dump and print_r; that's not the point.  a) I want a way to debug when a site is live (I know, that's bad but sometimes have to for a quick fix), b) dumping PHP variables all over a web page is ugly, and c) I sometimes need to know why AJAX calls aren't working, and it's easier to look at JSON in the console.

Possible other solutions include wrapping your debug output in a hidden div, e.g.

```
<div id="debug"><?php var_dump($all_the_junk) ?></div><script>document.getElementById('debug').style.display='none'</script>
```

and then typing something like

```
document.getElementById('debug')style.display = 'block'
```

into the console.

But let's be honest, that kind of sucks, and defeats the purpose of being able to see everything in a tidy way.

ENDEDIT;

So, anyways, I have the following code:

```
function log_as_json($vars)
{
    if(is_resource($vars)) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        if($vars)
        {
            $json =  @json_encode($vars);
            print "<script>console.log($json);</script>";
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that once in a while I get these terrible recursions, but I'm not sure what the best way is to check for types that json_encode supports.  Also I suspect there is a better way to do this.  Advice would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I like your implementation here, never even thought to put together a way to write to the console from PHP. Can't comment on if this is the best way to do it, but thanks for sharing.

Comment: The point is that I don't always know the anatomy of what's being passed in.  It could be a file object, or an object, or an array that is several layers deep, or anything else.  I want the function to fail if json_encode can't deal with it.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to send it to the client, can't you log it to a file or a database and check that?

Comment: Security 101: **never ever never** debug on a live site.

Comment: I know.  There are sometimes cases where something breaks and needs to be fixed.  Also, I sometimes need to debug AJAX.

Comment: The point is that anybody could be using the function, and it should fail safely no matter what is passed to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are really keen on debugging in the browser, I'd recommend [Chrome Logger](http://craig.is/writing/chrome-logger) (formerly known as ChromePHP).

Comment: Yeah.  I'm going to try that, it looks good.  I had a look at how he solves the exact same problem, and I'm probably going to post it here.

Comment: you can also use firebug+firePHP on firefox

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) And an IDE that allows you to set breakpoints

Comment: There is also [firephp](http://www.firephp.org/) a plugin for firebug in the firefox browser. I've never used it but, it would probably fit your 'in the browser' criteria. 

My current favorite is using Netbeans for PHP development, mostly because of the improved HTML5 + web support. Otherwise Eclipse is a good choice as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [var_dump](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) - it is what they are designed for.

I suppose you could embed these calls in `console.log` - not sure how they would display though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but here is a way that works for me, just call the function when you need to..

```
function console_log( $data ){
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'console.log('. json_encode( $data ) .')';
    echo '</script>';
}
```